# railsでform_tagを使うとき、モデルでバリデーションをかける方法。

Tags: ruby-on-rails

DBとは関係なく、form_tagで入直値をもらい、getでその値をコントローラに渡すようにしています。
ここで入力フォームにバリデーションをかけたいんですけど、DBを利用しなくてもモデルを作成し、そこでバリデーションをかけるんでしょうか。
方法がありましたらモデル、コントローラ、ヴューにどう作成すればいいか教えていただきたいんです。
ちなみに自分がやっているところはRails Engineで作られています。

下記は自分のコードです。

view

```
= form_tag(history_histories_path, method: 'get') do
  = label_tag :名前
  = text_field_tag :name
  br
  = submit_tag '検索する'
  br
```

controller

```
def index
end

def history
  @name = params[:name] 

   ... 省略　...
end
```

routes

```
Admin::Engine.routes.draw do
  controller :application do
    resources :histories, only: [:index] do
      get :history, on: :collection
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveModel を利用すると、データベースに関連づけないモデルも ActiveRecord と同様の枠組みでデータを取り扱うことができます。Controller/View は ActiveRecord を利用する場合と同様に作成してください。

app/models/application_form.rb:

```
class ApplicationForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :age

  validates :name, :presence => true, :length => (1..10)
  validates :age, :numericality => true
end
```

実行結果:

```
af = ApplicationForm.new(:name => "foo", :age => 100)
af.valid?
# => true

af = ApplicationForm.new(:name => "", :age => 100)
af.valid?
# => false

af = ApplicationForm.new(:name => "foo", :age => "bar")
af.valid?
# => false
```

**追記**

エラーメッセージは ActiveRecord の場合と同様に取得できます。

```
af = ApplicationForm.new(:name => "", :age => 100)
af.valid?
# => false
af.errors
# => #<ActiveModel::Errors>
af.errors.messages
# => {:name=>["can't be blank", "is too short (minimum is 1 character)"]}
af.errors.full_messages
# => ["Name can't be blank", "Name is too short (minimum is 1 character)"]
af.errors.full_messages_for(:name)
# => ["Name can't be blank", "Name is too short (minimum is 1 character)"]
```

Comment: 回答、ありがとうございます。無事実行はできましたが、af.valid?以外にname, age別々でどんなバリデーションにかかったのか知る方法はありませんでしょうか？どこにどんな問題があるのかに対してエラーメッセージを送るようにしようと思っていまして...